# Плагин для TinyMce v4

Tags: jquery, javascript, tinymce

Доброго времени суток. Нужно сделать плагин для **TinyMce v4**.
Суть плагина такова, есть некий JSON массив со списком фотографий т.е.

```
{images:{id:150,name:'imeges1.jpg'}, id:151,name:'imeges2.jpg'}, id:152,name:'imeges3.jpg'}]}
```

Нужно сделать так, что бы в **TinyMce v4** открывалось окно, в окне формировался стисок фотографий и при выборе какой то фотографии (нажать на фото) в текст вставлялся тег {images-152} который бы не выделялся тегами `<p></p>`. А если как то возможно то вставлялась бы еще и сама картинка, но при условии, что в коде все таки был тег {images-152}

Comment: Покажите, на каком шаге вы застряли, мы подскажем!

Comment: не понимаю как в окно вставить HTML код,а потом при нажатии на фото закрыть это и при этом вставить тег

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если подключаешь `min` библиотеку, то:

../plugins/pasteImage/plugin.min.js

Если `full`, то

../plugins/pasteImage/plugin.js

Содержание плагина:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('PasteImage', function(editor, url) {
    // Adds a menu item to the tools menu
    editor.addMenuItem('PasteImage', {
        text: 'PasteImage plugin',
        context: 'tools',
        onclick: function() {
            var images = [
                {image: 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/870c227ab02e5c61101a8265cdd14989?s=128&d=identicon&r=g' , id: '120'},
                {image: 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/870c227ab02e5c61101a8265cdd14989?s=128&d=identicon&r=g' , id: '123'},
                {image: 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/870c227ab02e5c61101a8265cdd14989?s=128&d=identicon&r=g' , id: '142'},
            ];

            for(var i=0, html = ''; i < images.length; i++) {
                html += "<img src='" + images[i].image + "' style='width:190px;margin: 10px;' data-paste='{images-" + images[i].id + "}'>";
            }

            // Open window with a specific url
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Choise image',
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                html: html,
                buttons: [{text: 'Закрыть', onclick: 'close'}],
                onclick: function(ed) {
                    ed.preventDefault();

                    if(ed.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
                        editor.insertContent(ed.target.outerHTML);
                        var win = editor.windowManager.getWindows()[0];
                        win.close();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

В `init`:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: 'PasteImage'
 });
```

Comment: Хм интересно, а не хотели бы вы написать все модули которые мне требуются для TinyMce v4

https://www.fl.ru/projects/2023450/plaginyi-dlya-vizualnogo-redaktora-tinymce-v4.html

Comment: Чуть поправил и прямо то, что надо 

    if(ed.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
                            editor.insertContent(ed.target.outerHTML);
                            var win = editor.windowManager.getWindows()[0];
                            win.close();
    
                        }

Comment: @Abitlord могу написать.

Comment: хорошо, если вы есть на фрилансе, то выберите как исполнитель

Comment: @Abitlord а если меня там нет? Оставьте свой емеил тут: b33293@drdrb.net я вам напишу.

Comment: отправил сообщение